# Overly complicated many-to-many relationship with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While researching whether or not ASP.NET MVC is suited for my next website, I've come across an annoying issue.

I have followed ASP.NET MVC since version 2, and it's gotten better. For instance, it's now fairly easy to get going with migrations in the entity framework with code first, which used to be a hassle.
This means that I now can get running with a database migrations and code first within half an hour (as I usually don't remember the steps involved, I have to follow a guide I wrote).

Now, fairly early on I always get a many-to-many relationship between entities (e.g. tags and posts) in my database, and what I've found is that getting this relationship exposed via MVC framework is surprisingly complicated! [Example from asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) [Example from mikesdotnetting](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/110/ASP.NET-MVC-Entity-Framework-Modifying-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-Many-Relationships)

It involves special methods to retrieve the relationship's data that is not an inherent part of the framework.

Is there really no better/easier way of treating the many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a virtual key word to the Many port

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get;set;}
}

public class Tag 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes. Maybe I have to clarify that it is not this part that is causing me problems. My problem is the _exposure_ of this relationship through the controller, where, according to the links I have included, you need to create a special function that combines the two (post and tag).

Comment: You should be able to get the linked collection with `Post.Tags` and `Tag.Posts`. If those collections are empty, you probably need to use `PostsIQuerriable.Include(x => x.Tags)` (and vica versa) to lead the data. If you get errors about infinite looping when accessing this data in your view, it could be that you need the [ScriptIgnore] tag.